# Magento - How to see if product has related products from list.phtml

Tags: magento

I need a way to check if the product has related products from the category listing.

From this file: `/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml`

** Edit **

If there is a way to successfully call getChildHtml('relatedProducts') (originally found in `view.phtml`) from `list.phtml` then the problem should be solved however I cannot do this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was able to solve this by calling:

```
$_product->getRelatedProductIds();
```